# PHP variable inserted into JS script

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have a php variable obtained from a post:

```
<?php
$pdf_name = $_POST['pdf_name']; 
echo $pdf_name;
?>
```

When I insert it into the flipbook script I get an error:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#read").flipBook({
            //Layout Setting
            pdfUrl:'uploads/pdf-gallery/<?php  $pdf_name ?>',
            lightBox:true,
            ...............
            ...............
            ............... etc.
        });
      })
  </script>
```

This is the ERROR:

```
pdfUrl:'uploads/pdf-gallery/<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined variable $pdf_name in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\pdf-gallery.php</b> on line <b>81</b><br />
<br />
```

While if I insert this variable it works well and I get:

```
<?php 
$pdf_name = 'tex-willer.pdf';
echo $pdf_name;
?>


<script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#read").flipBook({
            //Layout Setting
            pdfUrl:'uploads/pdf-gallery/tex-willer.pdf',
            lightBox:true,
            ........... etc
 </script>
```

How can I eliminate the error from the first situation???

Comment: `<?php  $pdf_name ?>` doesn't do anything, you'd need to output/echo it

Comment: And make sure $pdf_name exists and is in scope at the time you try to use it

Comment: Demo: https://3v4l.org/qMVuH

Comment: You additionally should url_encode it. `<?php echo urlencode($pdf_name); ?>`

Comment: Demo including Markus' sensible suggestion: https://3v4l.org/D9uSR

Comment: Alternatively, `<?= $str ?>` is a shorter syntax (you still need to escape it though). In general I would strongly advise the use of Twig, which solves escaping and variable scope problems, among many others.

Comment: I could not reproduce your exact error, but `$pdf_name` should be in scope. What’s probably happening is that `$_POST['pdf_name']` is not defined, but I could not reproduce your exact error.

Comment: @Mat if the POST variable wasn't defined, that would cause a [different error](https://3v4l.org/mEkY5)

Comment: @ADyson That does cause a warning, but I wouldn't be surprised if certain PHP configurations or versions could ignore the warning until the variable is referenced and then throw an error. Unless you are certain such a situation odd impossible?

Comment: @Mat what do you mean exactly? The OP is already getting another warning (they showed this in the question). If you see one warning, you'll see all warnings. You can suppress all warnings, or none. There's no in-between. `ignore the warning until the variable is referenced` ... well `$pdf_name = $_POST['pdf_name']; ` _is_ referencing that POST variable, so that's where it would throw the warning, if it wasn't populated.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it with SESSION:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['pdf_name'])) {
$pdf_name = $_POST['pdf_name'];
$_SESSION['pdf_name'] = $pdf_name;

echo $_SESSION['pdf_name'] ;
}
?>
```

Comment: Unless the `echo $_SESSION['pdf_name'] ;` is in a different file, then this wouldn't help anything. If you're still in the same script, you don't need the Session. And your original objective was to output it into the SQL script, not just to echo it randomly. Either you haven't explained this clearly, or your problem was not the one described in the question.

Answer (score -2):

I inserted an alert and it works also  in the first situation

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert('<?=$pdf_name; ?>');
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure how this helps you resolve your original issue?

Comment: This suggests to me that the shorter `<?= ... ?> ` fixes the scope problem. Why don't you try it with your original JavaScript code?

Comment: @Mat the way you open and close a PHP block has no impact on scope

Comment: You’re right, in both cases `$pdf_name` is in scope.

Comment: I need  $pdf_name  generate from POST,  as in first  example, not  from text.
`code`
$pdf_name = $_POST['pdf_name']; 
echo $pdf_name;
`code`